# ManyToOne relation Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a many to one relation between my entities.
An application can have activities

```
<?php

namespace AppAcademic\ApplicationBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Activity
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Activity
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppAcademic\ApplicationBundle\Entity\Application", inversedBy="activity")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="application_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $application;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


    public function setApplication($application)
    {
        $this->application = $application;

        return $this;
    }


    public function getApplication()
    {
        return $this->application;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return Activity
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }


}
```

And the application

```
/**
 * Application
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppAcademic\ApplicationBundle\Entity\ApplicationRepository")
 */
class Application
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppAcademic\ApplicationBundle\Entity\Activity", mappedBy="application")
     */
    protected $activities;

    ...

}
```

I have this in the profiler:

```
AppAcademic\ApplicationBundle\Entity\Application    
The mappings AppAcademic\ApplicationBundle\Entity\Application#activities and AppAcademic\ApplicationBundle\Entity\Activity#application are inconsistent with each other.
AppAcademic\ApplicationBundle\Entity\Application    
The mappings AppAcademic\ApplicationBundle\Entity\Application#activities and AppAcademic\ApplicationBundle\Entity\Activity#application are inconsistent with each other.
AppAcademic\ApplicationBundle\Entity\Activity   
The association AppAcademic\ApplicationBundle\Entity\Activity#application refers to the inverse side field AppAcademic\ApplicationBundle\Entity\Application#activity which does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the mapping annotation `ManyToOne` on the `Activity::$application` property, the attribute

```
inversedBy="activity"
```

This should be

```
inversedBy="activities"
```